# How to drive three 3W LEDs from a USB power supply (5V/1A)?

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

So I'm currently trying out a project using a USB power source to drive an Arduino Nano board and several 3W LEDs.

Specific conditions the project needs to fulfill are:

- The power supply's standard output is restricted to 5V/1A.
- The LEDs and arduino need to be powered in parallel
- Prefer to keep the overall size of the end product small (perhaps around the size of a flashlight).

So far I've managed to rule out powering the arduino with the on-board USB input and instead use a power supply only USB cable.

I currently plan to use at least one of these [DC-DC boost converter modules](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01GRIQBRY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to boost the 5V/1A output to at least 12V/1A before futzing with anything else.

The questions I have are:

1. Is it possible to place a couple of these boosters in a series to increase the voltage still further?
2. What would I need to add to supply 1A of current to all of the LEDs off of the single output?

And if there's anything I'm missing, can someone point out the errors?

Comment: If you look at the power of your supply: 5*1=5W it will never be able to power the 3*3W. You could turn down the brightness.
You will also not be able to create 12V/1A from 5V/1A, without another source...

Comment: Other than the error that you want a DC-DC switcher to magically convert a 5 W power input to a 12 W power output? If you need more voltage then use a power supply with a higher voltage output. Every supply will have an efficiency of 80-90% so if you have 5 V/1 A input then at 12 V the most you will get is 0.9*(5/12) = 375 mA

Comment: Yeah...sorry, my brain wasn't properly working when I started this line of thought because I had people wanting to use a USB powerbank to drive the whole assembly.

Side note: Given that USB-C allows up to a 15W supply (5V/3A?) it would be possible, if using a USB-C compatible powerbank to setup a way to drive both the Nano and the LEDs, right?

Comment: A 3W LED is a class of LED, it does not mean the LED could be driven or would be driven with 3 Watts of power.  Thermal management generally prevents driving an  LED at its max current.  In a manufacturers series of 3 Watt LEDs there is usually only one LED that can be driven with 3 Watts but still it is rarely driven at 3 Watts.  Calculate actual power requirements. You can drive the 3 Watt LEDs just not at their full 3 Watt output.  Many, if not most, are driven at 1 Watt or less.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a boost converter for generating 12V, and it's also possible to use several of them in series.
But it doesn't help in your case, because you can't generate 9W from a 5W power supply.

Consider also the efficiency of the booster. They promise "up to 94%", but I would rather assume about 80..85%*.

Next thing:
The booster in your link generates a constant output voltage. You can drive the LEDs with a constant voltage converter, but especially for High Power LEDs I would recommend a constant current converter, as the forward voltage is temperature dependent.

After all:
If you are sticked to the power supply, use a constant current buck driver and drive only one LED. 
If you need the power of more LEDs, then use a stronger power supply (and nevertheless switch to a constant current driver).

*) In a series connection of several boosters, you would have to multiply all efficiencies, so the overall efficiency was much lower.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do the task with your 5 Watts power supply, at least while LED's are on full power. DC boost converters will not help you in this case, because your problem is not with the voltage.

Comment: PWM doesn't help in this case, as you would still have to supply the peak current during ON time. What you could do is time multiplexing (what requires a more complex control circuit), so that each LED works at specified peak current, but only for 1/3 of the period - of course the overall light output is the same as of just one LED at full power.

Comment: @mic yeah, you are right. Editing

Comment: Thanks guys. I can now tell people to stop bothering me to use the 5W power supply for this project. (And sorry, I had a complete brain freeze when I posted this. Thank you for being so tolerant in answering this.)